# MYSQL 0.0.2 package is not installing when running pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, pip, mysql-python

I am trying to install the 'mysql' package ( Version 0.0.2) , using `pip install -r requirements.txt`

But I am facing the following error:

```
Collecting mysql==0.0.2
  Using cached mysql-0.0.2.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pwiwdipw/virtualenv/ITC/3.6/bin/python3.6_bin -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sbgj4igk/mysql_4feada7a9dca4cc6b8bf0981676447ec/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sbgj4igk/mysql_4feada7a9dca4cc6b8bf0981676447ec/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup;setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-yaqwy2z8
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sbgj4igk/mysql_4feada7a9dca4cc6b8bf0981676447ec/
  Complete output (28 lines):
  WARNING: `mysql` is a virtual package. Please use `%s` as a dependency directly.

  running egg_info
  creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-yaqwy2z8/mysql.egg-info
  writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-yaqwy2z8/mysql.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-sbgj4igk/mysql_4feada7a9dca4cc6b8bf0981676447ec/setup.py", line 42, in <module>
      url="https://github.com/valhallasw/virtual-mysql-pypi-package",
    File "/home/pwiwdipw/virtualenv/ITC/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/pwiwdipw/virtualenv/ITC/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 292, in run
      writer(self, ep.name, os.path.join(self.egg_info, ep.name))
    File "/home/pwiwdipw/virtualenv/ITC/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 656, in write_pkg_info
      metadata.write_pkg_info(cmd.egg_info)
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 1106, in write_pkg_info
      self.write_pkg_file(pkg_info)
    File "/home/pwiwdipw/virtualenv/ITC/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 188, in write_pkg_file
      license = rfc822_escape(self.get_license())
    File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/distutils/util.py", line 474, in rfc822_escape
      lines = header.split('\n')
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/5f/b574ac9f70811df0540e403309f349a8b9fa1a25d3653824c32e52cc1f28/mysql-0.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=55e66b5e7b3823b1da5fb2a063e95a628fb850b2a0b76bdcd884faac5d2daa7d(from https://pypi.org/simple/mysql/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql==0.0.2 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysql==0.0.2
```

Steps taken to try to solve the issue:

1.I have tried changing the versions , yet the package is still not installing.

2.Manually trying to install it , using pip install mysql==0.0.2, instead of installing from requirements.txt

How do I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Upgrade to 0.0.3. The version you are trying to use in 7 years old and only supports python2, which has been EOL since 2020.

Comment: I tried, but im getting another error saying  `compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: Most common reason for that is missing the native (C) mysql development libraries. How you install those depends on OS.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow that package's instructions:

https://pypi.org/project/mysql

> mysql 0.0.3
>
> ... or mysqlclient (Python 3) ...
>
> Instead of depending on this package, please depend on the relevant package directly.

This means installing https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mysqlclient ,
for which [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) will install
both the pure python code and the binary dependencies.
Conda won't require you to have a working `gcc` compiler installed.